# How do capture audio using Python?

Tags: audio, python

More particularly: How can I use python with ALSA to capture audio input?

I'm thinking about doing an oled-based spectrum analyzer for Pi-based audioplayer. One part of the solution is to read the audio currently playing. I've tried this using ALSA in Python:

```
import alsaaudio
inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NONBLOCK)
```

At this point the script dies:

> alsaaudio.ALSAAudioError: No such file or directory

Adding a card like this doesn't work either:

```
card = 'sysdefault:CARD=ALSA'
inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NONBLOCK, card)
```

I've seen various related posts on raspbian, but no solution.

Comment: See also http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1536/8926

Comment: You can try PyAudio (Bindings for PortAudio, the cross-platform audio input/output stream library.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the Raspberry Pi has the necessary hardware to capture audio input. You can confirm this running `alsamixer`.

[image]

That would explain why `alsaaudio.ALSAAudioError` exception was thrown by `alsaaudio.PCM.__init__` method.

#### Explore third party USB devices

I've enjoyed an article entitled [*Speech Recognition with the Raspberry Pi*](https://sites.google.com/site/observing/Home/speech-recognition-with-the-raspberry-pi); which, outlined the steps needed for adding audio input. [*Raspberry Pi into an audio spying device*](http://mutsuda.com/2012/09/07/raspberry-pi-into-an-audio-spying-device/) is also helpful with USB-microphone installs. The underlining theme is to ensure that the base system is configured & ready to capture audio through ALSA before developing an application.

#### Module `alsaaudio` is well documented

Alsaaudio ships with [test suites](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/pyalsaaudio.html#testing) to verify that you local install is fully functional.

```python
bash> cd pyalsaaudio-0.7
bash> python recordtest.py -c NAME_OF_USB_CARD output.wav
```

The **NAME_OF_THE_USB_CARD** should be a name listed by [alsaaudio.cards()](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/libalsaaudio.html#alsaaudio.cards)'s method; which, is the same name for the third parameter for [alsaaudio.PCM](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/libalsaaudio.html#pcm-objects) class.

Comment: Mhm. Running alsamixer I do not get the capture controls message shown above. Instead, a volume control is shown?

Comment: Press `F4` for capture controls. `F3` for playback & `F5` for all controls. Use `F6` to switch between sound cards.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error with code which works perfectly with my USB mic on Ubuntu but refused to work on RaspberryPi.

First, since the question was asked, `card` is outdated and replaced with `device`.

Second, I had to run `alsaaudio.pcms(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE)` and use EXACT FULL line of that output as device. In my case it was full line `"hw:CARD=SHG7980,DEV=0"`. Just 'SHG7980`, '0' or whatsoever else didn't work.