# Using digital microphone with my pi

Tags: audio, camera

I wanted to ask, can I connect a digital microphone to my pi somehow, so that the input will be digital and then to use the data and convert it to an audio file?
If so, what should I get and how do I convert it?
The reason is that I want to record video with mycamera pi and combine it with audio, but I haven't found any good way to connect microphone.
Thank you.

Comment: Here is another link you can try this maybe it will help you https://github.com/nejohnson2/rpi-i2s/blob/master/README.md thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using something like this http://www.adafruit.com/product/1475

They have a neat tutorial that will help you interface it.

Comment: This one is a great option, thank you. However, it will take very long until I I'll get it by mail. Therefore, is there any other eay, maybe even more complicated way?

Comment: The other option would be to hookup the microphone to a ADC via an opamp and then process the data. Not sure you can convert the analog values to audio though.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/can-i-get-audio-input-through-the-gpio

Comment: That Adafruit USB sound card page does contain the warning: "we don't recommend it if you need Mic input"

Comment: Thats weird cause I used the same tutorial to interface the microphone with my RPi about a year ago.