# Raspberry Pi and realtime audio effects / digital signal processing?

Tags: hardware, audio

I'm trying to understand if it would be possible (and, in case, what is the best approach) to build an "effect box" which could take an analog signal (from a guitar or a microphone), change it in realtime in order to apply some "audio effects" (from simple delay to complex time/frequency operations) and finally output it back into the analog world.

I know there are really powerful (and costly!) digital audio processors out there, but this it is some kind of home, spare-time project, and I'd like to take the chance to learn something more on the subject =)

The first thing I wish to understand is the hw support I should expect or add to it in order to get the sound sampled and then played.

From what I read the built-in audio output is quite poor and there's no easy way to record audio (see [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/how-can-i-record-audio-using-a-microphone) and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/can-i-get-audio-input-through-the-gpio))..
So I guess I'd better plug some external audio device...

Is it better an [external USB audio interface](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Sound_Cards) or [some kind of ADC/DAC attached to the GPIO bus](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/how-can-i-connect-an-analog-to-digital-converter-adc) (which are often using the I2C bus through the [P5 header](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals#P5_header))?

Is it worth trying? 
Does someone has some insight about this? 
Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: there's no audio input and audio output quality is quite poor. choose another device to play with, select one that has at least audio in and out working properly.

Comment: well.. I had some suspect that it could be a troublesome path, and sometimes even a "no way" is a good place to start with: you know you have to switch to another road =)

Comment: If you can get usb sound card that has sufficient quality for you, it should be thoretically possible.

Comment: Look into the I2S interface which is supposedly more along the audio processing avenue.

Answer (score 9):

It is very much possible to use the Pi for realtime audio effects. The only limitations are the need for an external USB soundcard (not all soundcards are supported yet, but I know some people are working on it), and of course the power of the Pi itself (I managed to get a latency of 15 ms with some heavy FFT though, so there's a lot you can do before you reach the limits of the Pi).

I use Pure Data for all the DSP.
You can see a demo I made on my blog :
http://guitarextended.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/real-time-guitar-effects-with-raspberry-pi-pd-and-arduino/

I hope to be able to document this better in the near future, when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

The rp is a - by today's standards - mediocre to slow computer running linux normally. Whatever sound effects software runs on linux with those specs is likely to run on the Pi. You could also connect a faster "Black Box" that does most of the calculating to it, if it is not fast enough.