# Can a Raspberry Pi be used to make voice changer?

Tags: audio

There are voice modulators for over $150, and all they do is alter the pitch and put a static burst when there is a silence of over 0.5 seconds. Surely this can be done on a Raspberry Pi with a USB microphone and a speaker.

Anyone working on something like this?  I am new to programming, but am willing to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I think correct way to start is to introduce yourself with signal processing with Raspberry Pi with the help of Google.

I guess this question with its answer can you lead to right track:
[Raspberry Pi and realtime audio effects / digital signal processing?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7791/raspberry-pi-and-realtime-audio-effects-digital-signal-processing)