# How can I make Voice distorter with RPi

Tags: raspbian, python, audio, audio-playback

How can I make a voice distorter using m raspberry pi, I've got a generic USB sound card with a mic input and audio output. I want it to change and output the audio in real time, also how can I make it autorun when the Pi is turned on. Still new to Python 
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-make-voice-changer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SunVox](http://www.warmplace.ru/soft/sunvox/) for that. It's free (not OSS though) and runs on Raspberry Pi just fine. It's not available in repositories, you'll have to download it and copy into a location you intend to run it from.

Once you've got it running, delete all the modules but `Output`, add modules `Input` and `Distortion`, then connect them, so sound flows from `Input`, through `Distortion` and to `Output`. Direction is important! Adjust `Distort`'s properties on the left until you're satisfied with the output. And there you have it!

Setting it up to work headlessly will be tricky, should you need it, because SunVox is a GUI application and requires mouse input to work. You could set up some sort of remote access, such as VNC, and work that way. I have no idea what the performance will be though, my first RPi2 is currently on its way to me :(